# handlebars-helpers /node_modules/log-utils/ cannot statically analyse 'require(..., ...)' webpack

Tags: webpack, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I am installing the handlebars-helpers to my project.

After I added the "unlazy-loader" to my webpack file, the issue of

> WARNING in ./node_modules/create-frame/utils.js 3:34-41
> Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

got resolved, however, I got an error:

> ./node_modules/logging-helpers/node_modules/log-utils/index.js
> Cannot statically analyse 'require(..., ...)' in line 21

Answer (score 0):

It seems it has been a long time since the last time `handlebars-helpers` and `logging-helpers` updated.

So there are some dependencies outdated.

I solved this issue by edit the `node_modules/logging-helpers/package.json`

updated it to:

```
"dependencies": {
    "isobject": "^3.0.0",
    "log-utils": "0.3.0"
  },
```

also, I updated the package-lock.json.

Then the issue got resolved.